# Expression for "embracing the accusations"?

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms

Is there an expression that refers to the phenomenon of embracing accusations/rumours made against you? So, for example, if a child is told constantly that they are bad, they might grow up to be a bad person, because eventually they begin to believe that they are.

I've seen "manifest destiny" but this isn't really the normal use of this phrase.

Comment: Please finish reading the [Tour] and the Help on asking questions. You are required to provide an example sentence for this kind of question so we know how you wish to use a phrase.

Comment: This may be a matter of *owning it*, like taking on the labels queer or the N word. Making lemons out of lemonade.

Comment: @YosefBaskin If this question gets reopened, then yours sounds very much like an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called **Self-fulfilling prophecy.**

According to *Wikipedia*:

> A *self-fulfilling prophecy* is a prediction that comes true at least in part as a result of a person's or group of persons' belief or expectation that said prediction would come true. This suggests that people's beliefs influence their actions. The principle behind this phenomenon is that people create consequences regarding people or events, based on previous knowledge of the subject.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for! :)